# Svn error shows that my svn repository is not a working copy

Tags: svn

I am trying to work with svn and so have installed svn with the help of several guides available online in my Ubuntu 12.04 computer. I am able to add as many repositories as i want, but am not able to add any files or folders into it. Neither am I able to commit. The error shows that my svn repository is not a working copy. When I try to view the repo in my browser, I am able to see all the repositories I created. But even there I have a problem. The browser is not asking for any credential that I had given to login.

Can anyone suggest about what should be done??

Comment: SVN works as a client-server. What you have installed is the server side which contains (stores) repositories. Clients do not add files/folder directly on the server, but have to create their own working copies locally first, with **svn checkout** command. This probably looks confusing to you as you will probably run both server and a client on the same physical machine (your Ubuntu). Once you have your working copy, add/modify/delete files here and then perform **svn commit** which sends the data to repository on server. To the credentials, you probably allowed read access, so you can view it

Comment: Why does it show that svn: '.' is not a working copy ??

Comment: svn checkout is working fine but am  not able to add a file or folder in my repo